# QMAKE : Generated VS Project and Ampersand

Tags: project, qmake, ampersand, generated

I use QMAKE to generate a Visual Studio Project which contain a path with whitespaces, ex : `C:\Program Files...`

I need to add the `&quot;` tag (the 6 characters html tag and not the real quote, that's what VS need) before and after the path ($$quote does not work). But when i write `&quot;` in my .pro , qmake translate it by `&amp;quot;`.

Is there a way to avoid that ? Using a special function, ascii code or something ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found how to add the quote tag (not directly the ampersand symbol but i don't care), simply use `'"'` to add `&quot;` and it would work.